# Unable to change Location in Windows XP when trying to add user

Tags: domain, windows-xp, remote-desktop

I am trying to add domain users to "Remote Desktop" in Windows XP 32 bit. Problem is I am unable to change location from local pc to domain. Check the following screenshot and you will see location is set to WINXP32 which is my local machine.

Whether I login as domain administrator or local administrator doesn't matter as it stays the same. How to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would try two things here:

1. in the select users window, try typing the full name of the domain user ie 'pdc\username' and click on check name.
2. removed the machine from the domain back into a workgroup, reboot, add back to domain, reboot and try adding a user again.

Comment: Tried both options but didn't work.